# getting a tkinter label to not interact with other labels in grid

Tags: python, tkinter

i've got a problem with my programming whereby column=0,row=0/TITLE interacts with column=2,row=1 / "text1" and row=2,column=2 / "text2". The problem is that "TITLE pushes "text1" and "text2" to the right while its not even in the same column. Does anybody know how to get "text 1" and "text2" to just stand in the middle like normally? 
this is my sample code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk
master = Tk()

Label(master, text="TITLE", font=("Courier", 60)).grid(columnspan=2)
Label(master, text="small title1", font=("Courier", 15)).grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="small title2", font=("Courier", 15)).grid(row=2)
tkinter.ttk.Separator(master, orient=VERTICAL).grid(column=1, row=1,rowspan=8, sticky='ns')
Label(master, text="text1", font=("Courier", 15)).grid(row=1, column=2)
Label(master, text="text2", font=("Courier", 15)).grid(row=2, column=2)
```

[[image: [1]]

How it looks when I run the program

Comment: Souldn't the two last labels be in column 2?

Comment: yes, thanks. but the problem is that it doesn't change! except the texts go a bit to the left but not fully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `columnspan=4` on the TITLE label. This works, don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

`columnspan=3` means it occupies columns 0, 1, and 2. Since your other widgets are in column 3, and by definition column 3 is to the right of column 2, anything in column 3 must be to the right of widgets in column 2.

If you change your columnspan to 4, the title will occupy columns 0, 1, 2, and 3, which means the title will be above items in column 3 rather than to the left of them.

Comment: See, trial and error works but knowledge works even better. Thanks Bryan.